# Git Submodules Awareness in VS Code Not Working

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Using version 1.22.2. According to the [release notes from VS Code 1.2](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_source-control), there's supposed to be an awareness of Git submodules. However, I can't seem to get this feature to work:

1. Open a folder containing a git project that in turn contains submodules
2. Make a change in one of the submodules
3. Observe that the source control view merely states the submodule object changed in the main repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is basic support in place which lets you stage, unstage or discard submodule changes in the outer repository. You can disable automatic submodule detection with the git.detectSubmodules setting.

I suspect "submodule changes" are only the top tree SHA1 (the gitlink) recorded in the parent repo index, not the files within that submodule.

The gitlink is the diff shown in the picture seen in the release notes:

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_20/submodules.png]

Comment: Ah, I see... sort of. How is this better than what existed before? Seemed VS Code always knew I was changing the submodule content. Also, how did they open that diff view? I know how to view diffs on a file, but not a diff view showing those changes to the subproject commit.

Comment: It now list that new change (gitlink)